# is it possible to monitor the /var/log/secure or /var/log/message using watch command

Tags: watch

When I was trying to monitor the `/var/log/secure` or `/var/log/message` using watch command the output showed as `/var/log/messages: Permission denied`. Is it possible to monitor the `/var/log/messages` and /var/log/secure using watch command?

Comment: You cannot `watch` a file, you have to give it a command to run, like Ulrich Schwarz's answer with `tail`.  For a file, you can just use `tail -f` instead of `watch`.

Comment: As an extra tip, some files like `/var/log/secure` may rotate while tailing them, causing `tail -f` to stop printing logs. To continue following even if the file is rotated, use `tail -F`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is, but note that regular users don't have permission to read `/var/log/messages` and `/var/log/secure`.

```
sudo watch tail /var/log/messages
```

worked fine here when I tried.

Comment: Hi Ulrich Schwarz,                                                                                        im using centos 6.7 , i used root account rather than normal user account, i got the error message when i was using root account only.

Comment: Note that most sensible distros will make log files owned `root adm` and mode `0640` so anyone in the `adm` group can read them. If so, `adduser regularjoe adm` will allow `regularjoe` to read them once he logs in again.

Answer (score 1):

You only have to issue:

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/messages
```

This will continuously add the latest line to the screen or file.